# Measure on $\mathbb{N}$ which has measure $1/n^2$ at each point $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I am stuck on the converse of this question:

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{A}=2^\mathbb{N}$, and let $\mu$ be the measure on $\mathbb{N}$ which has measure $1/n^2$ on each point $n$.

Let $f(n)=\sqrt n$ be defined on $\mathbb{N}$. Show that $f\in L^p$ if and only if $1\leq p<2$.

I managed to do the backwards direction (which I suspect may have a mistake), and cannot prove the forward direction.

My proof of the backwards direction: Assume $1\leq p<2$. Then

$\begin{align}
\|f\|_p^p&=\int n^{p/2}\cdot \chi_n d\mu\ \ \ \text{where}\ \chi_n\ \text{is the indicator function}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{p/2}\cdot \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{p/2-2}
\end{align}$

Since $-1.5\leq p/2-2<-1$, the infinite series converges (by the p-series test), and hence $f\in L^p$. I think I have made a mistake somewhere, either that or the question has a mistake. I can't do the forward direction.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The series $\sum_n n^{p/2-2}$ is convergent if and only if $p/2-2 < -1$, i.e $p<2$. Where is the problem? (recall that by definition of $L^p$ space, $p \ge 1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof works in both directions.
From your computations wee have that $f \in L^p$ if and only if

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^{2-p/2}}
$$

converges. By the $p$-series test, this converges if and only if $2-p/2>1$, that is $p < 2$.

The only reason I can see for the lower bound on $p$ you have ($p \geq 1$) is that we usually consider $L^p$ for $p \in [1, + \infty]$ as for $p \in [0,1)$ they are not normed spaces. That series is definitely convergent for $p \in [0, 2)$.

Comment: I see! The lower bound was what was bothering me. Thanks